# How to draw BitmapFont to fill rectangular region?

Tags: libgdx

With `SpriteBatch`, I can use this method to stretch a `TextureRegion` to fill a fixed "world region"

```
/** Draws a rectangle with the bottom left corner at x,y and stretching the region to cover the given width and height. */
    public void draw (TextureRegion region, float x, float y, float width, float height)
```

Is there an equivalent method in `BitmapFont` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't. If you need different sizes of fonts you need to create them and add them to the assets individually, or you can use Gdx Freetype which generates them on the fly (thus saving a lot of space).

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype

As link-only answers are not valid in here, I will just copy the relevant parts of the wiki entry for completeness:

Download the latest nightly build.

Open libgdx-nightly-latest.zip/extensions/gdx-freetype and do the following:

```
extract gdx-freetype.jar and gdx-freetype-natives.jar to your core project's libs folder
link gdx-freetype.jar to your core, android and desktop project
link gdx-freetype-natives.jar to your desktop project
copy armeabi/libgdx-freetype.so to your android project's libs/armeabi folder
copy armeabi-v7a/libgdx-freetype.so to your android project's libs/armeabi-v7a folder
```

In code:

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new
FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/myfont.ttf"));
BitmapFont font12 = generator.generateFont(12); // font size 12 pixels
BitmapFont font25 = generator.generateFont(25); // font size 25 pixels
generator.dispose(); // don't forget to dispose to avoid memory leaks!
```

Comment: What does it mean by `link gdx-freetype.jar to your core, android and desktop project` and `link gdx-freetype-natives.jar to your desktop project`? Do I have to copy those jars into those projects' libs folders? I have done that but on Desktop I can't see anything the generated font draw and I can't even run on Android

Comment: Oh I figured that out, no need to copy. And I forgot to change the font color to something different than white :p

Comment: So what was the solution?